# Create copies of Oracle database tables in an SQLite database

Tags: oracle, sqlite, synchronization, copy

I have 2 databases, Oracle and SQlite. And I want to create exact copies of some of the Oracle tables in SQLite in one of my applications. Most of these tables contains more than 10,000 rows so copying each table by going through each row programmatically is not efficient. Also the table structure may change in the future so I want to achieve this using a generic way without hard-coding the SQL statements. Is there a any way to do this?

p.s. - This application is being developed using Qt framework. All the queries and databases are represented by QtSql module objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't help with Qt framework, but for large amounts of data is is usually better to use bulk-copy operations.

Export data from Oracle
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/impexp.htm#BCEGAFAB

Import data into SQLite
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

IHTH

Comment: Thank you shelter, for your quick reply. But as it appears, this unloading must be done using Oracle Database XE graphical user interface or SQL*Loader. But is there any way I can do this in my application code? If it is possible, this will be the ideal solution.

Comment: There is almost always a way to run an external program from application code. It may be as simple as creating a command line like cmdLine="SQL*Loader out -oTabDelimited -T${TableName} -F ${outFilename}" and using the system cmd to run it, ie system(cmdLine); (This is just a general idea of how to do it, so look around in the help pages for your language your code is written in. (Qt?)  Look for a run cmd, system cmd, or ?? other. Then you can use that with variables like my example, and replicate as needed to manage all you db activities. Warning, DB management in code can get quite complex.

Answer (score 5):

What you probably really want to use is the [Oracle Database Mobile Server](http://bit.ly/fmiAre), which can automatically synchronize a SQLite and an Oracle Database.

The recent release of the Oracle Database Mobile Server (formally called Oracle Database Lite Mobile Server) supports synchronization between an Oracle Database and a SQLite or a Berkeley DB database running on the client. It supports both synchronous and asynchronous data exchange, as well as secure communications between client and server. You can configure the Mobile Server to synchronize based on several options without the need to modify the application that is accessing the database.

You can also find an excellent [discussion forum](http://bit.ly/gER2nw) for questions from developers and implementers using the Mobile Server.